# Structuring multiple pages within DOM for JavaScript web app

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm building a management app in which users have to type in a PIN, info is compared to a loaded variable, then the user continues on to a specific page designated for their department. From there, there will be a tree of about five pages that they can stem out to; all dynamic.

How should I manage multiple pages within the DOM?

Initially, my thoughts were to basically create an HTML tree, with a DIV for each department, then tree in the additional pages in that HTML tree, editing dynamic content with JavaScript when required.

I have done some research and came across solutions like templating engines and using iframes. I want this to be a firmly structured and stable application, so I don't think screwing around iframes would be the best solution.

Comment: are you open to using any frameworks?  They might simplify this....

Comment: Check out jQuery mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/

I once created a single-page app with multiple 'pages' (sections?) that were either hidden divs or iframes or ajax-loaded divs, then I created a "manager" object to record the current state of the page, like which section was active as well as contain functions that changed the page, animated things, etc. If i had make another, I think I would have used jQuery Mobile to do it.
PS: jquery mobile loads HTML pages via ajax, which is why it's useful. You might not need the jquery mobile UI stuff so much, but could be useful if you have mobile usr

Comment: @hvgotcodes jQuery, but i'm open to recommendations.

Comment: [This page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810086/recommended-javascript-framework-for-single-page-applications) may be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the best practices of the whatever framework you choose.  I recommend taking a look at [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/).  In ember (and sproutcore) you define views, which can be declared via template or programmatically.  So each section of your app would be a view, with subviews.  The benefits of ember are:

1) bindings that allow your views to update when their models change
2) a statechart mechanism that allows you to separate concerns and handle app logic
3) flexible view system
4) mechanisms that allow to do things you are going to want to do, like bind views to urls...

If I had to do it in straight js, I would probably develop the simplest possible view system that worked for my needs, to abstract the concept of a view away from the rendering of the dom.  I can't see any way to keep the code clean without it.